# famo.us: how to handle textbox.onchange events

Tags: famo.us

I don't see any tutorials with text input on famo.us university.  How can I add a text box surface to my app and handle `onchange` events?

Comment: I'm not sure why the long answer below (assuming it allows for more  control/customisation) but this seems to work for me, and I can't see a reason not to just do this: `(input = new InputSurface({ /*properties*/ })).on('change', function(e) { console.log(input.getValue()); });`

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hard to understand what you are looking to do.. But lets start out with your first question. There is currently no onchange handler option so if you want it now, you can write a subclass of InputSurface. By overriding the deploy function, while still calling InputSurface's deploy function, we can add the functionality we want, without messing around to much!

Here is a way you could add an onchange handler to a subclass of InputSurface. Just remember again onchange is only triggered after the InputSurface is blurred.

Good Luck!

```
var Engine            = require('famous/core/Engine');
var Surface           = require('famous/core/Surface');
var StateModifier     = require('famous/modifiers/StateModifier');
var EventHandler      = require('famous/core/EventHandler')
var InputSurface      = require('famous/surfaces/InputSurface')


function MyInputSurface(options) {
    InputSurface.apply(this, arguments);
    this.onchange = options.onchange;
    this._superDeploy = InputSurface.prototype.deploy;
}

MyInputSurface.prototype = Object.create(InputSurface.prototype);
MyInputSurface.prototype.constructor = MyInputSurface;

MyInputSurface.prototype.deploy = function deploy(target) {
  target.onchange = this.onchange;
  this._superDeploy(target);
};

var context = Engine.createContext();

var onchangeFunction = function(){ console.log("Text Changed!"); }

var myInput = new MyInputSurface({
  size: [200,60],
  onchange: onchangeFunction
})

context.add(new StateModifier({origin:[0.5,0.5]})).add(myInput);
```

Comment: Wait, doesn't an input surface pipe all events from Dom element to surface instance? Or only the click and touch events?

Comment: I believe it does now.. This is one of the many answers that may be outdated all to quickly.. :/ I'll check it out and make the update

Answer (score 0):

You could just compose 'select' element and put it as content to the surface.
After that, create listener for this surface: `surface.on('deploy', method)`.
In that method find created 'select' via `document.querySelector` and set `onchange` handler in which just emit 'change' event to the `this._eventOutput`/whatever.

Actual coffee file see here: https://gist.github.com/extempl/346c045c6c71b3345ac3